# changing user permissions using -R 755

Tags: file-permissions, sudo

I am trying to install a copy of magento and at the install wizard i am receiving a a long list of file paths that are not writeable and an error saying "the/file/path must be writable"

In the root folder that contains the directory for the magento site I have used

`sudo chmod -R 775 magentoFolder`

and re-run the wizard. I get the same list as before. I have considered as this has worked in the past, but recent reading has taught me `777` is a big NO NO! So apart from setting all my folders to `777` or individually changing each file, what other options do i have to resolve this?

Comment: What about running the installation wizard with sudo?

Comment: check the owner of the folder say if your path is magento/app go up to magento using cd magento then > type ll you will see its permissions try setting the permissions to your owner with chown -R owner:owner app/

Comment: @carlo I have tried using sudo and I get FAILED ERROR then lists parameters not passed, even though I have passed stated parameters

Comment: @HarshadaChavan the owner and group for the folder is the same as an install that is working

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to debug this is to:

- open a second terminal
- log in as web server user using the command su
- try to change into the requested directory and write a file there

Maybe the web server user cannot read the directory, because one of the parent directories is not accessible.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I cant get the password to work is this a different password to what I use when I sudo up? (i've tried several)

Comment: You should do `sudo -u web_server_user su`